# TensorFlow lightweight for prediction

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Is there anyway to install a lightweight version of TensorFlow for prediction only?

I built a Docker image with TensorFlow 2.5 and python 3.8 slim. The image size is 1.8Gb but I need it to be 1Gb maximum.

As I will only use this Docker image for prediction, I guess there must be a way to reduce TensorFlow and install only the needed modules.

If you know if TF lite or TF serving can help me to reach this out, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way yo use TF in a lightweight mode is using TFlite or TFLite Micro. For this to work yo need to convert your frozen inference graph to a .tflite file.